# Multiple remote target inferior processes in gdb

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to do

```
(gdb) add-inferior -copies 2 -exec <some-file>
```

and connect `remote target :5039` and `remote target :5040` simultaneously to inferiors 2 and 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not yet possible.  This is the [multi target](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/MultiTarget) project mentioned on the gdb wiki.